# Receptive fields calculous for spiking neural networks in python

Tags: python, encoding, neural-network, dataset, gaussian

I'd like to calculate the receptive fields (e.g. Gaussian) for spiking neural networks in python. Let's say that I want to encode the iris data set and transform it into spike trains. I work with Brian framework, and I'm looking for a way to encode my data sets.

Is there any way to do it automatically? Or even any site explaining the trasnformation process? I've read several papers but this process is explained partially ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is too broad, ill-defined, and vague to get a meaningful answer here.  There is no generic tool to do what you're asking.  I'm voting to close.

Comment: Im not talking about a generic tool, I just mean automatically (code? function?). Its suposed to be a very common way of encoding data sets with continuous features, and it is strange not to find a well-explained and standard solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For overlapping Gaussian RF, you need to know the minimum (`I_min`) and maximum (`I_max`) for **each** variable. Then, (again for **each** variable) you create an array of `N` input neurons located at the peaks of `N` overlapping Gaussians. Use the following formulas to space out the neurons evenly over the variable range (this is of course pseudocode):

```
range = I_max - I_min
for (i = 1..N)
    gaussian_i_mean = I_min + range * (2*i - 3) / (2 * (N - 2))
    gaussian_i_sd = range / (beta * (N - 2))
end for
```

`beta` controls the width of the Gaussian. See [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257786595_Evolving_spiking_neural_networks_A_Survey) paper for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot cantordust. Yes, I know the paper, but I dont understand what did to translate them into spike time delays. In Figure 2, I dont see the relationship between the triangles and the lower left figure.

Comment: The delay for each neuron amounts to the vertical offset at the current value. So in the example you have `v = 0.75`. Draw a vertical line and see where it intersects with each gaussian. The intersection point gives you an offset. For neuron 1 the vertical intersects the gaussian at around `0.8`, so neuron 1 fires at time `(1 - 0.8) = 0.2`. This is what the little dashes in the lower figure indicate. The higher the intersection point, the lower the delay. I hope this helps!

Comment: P.S. I find it useful to draw the gaussians inverted. Then the delay becomes simply the vertical offset rather than (1 - offset).

Comment: Ok cantordust, I already understand the Figure, your response has been very useful. Trying to understand the same approach in other papers, I found another example in [link](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0150329#sec019). In Figure 10, the approach is very similar, but I cannot understand how the spike train of 12 neurons (−1, −1, 14, 200, −1, 119, 7, −1, −1, −1, −1, −1) can be translated into delays: why the y-axis is a range 0-400? how to set the no firing zone? how to use the spike trains (−1, −1, 14, 200, −1, 119, 7, −1, −1, −1, −1, −1) in Brian framework?

Comment: The example is exactly the same as in the first paper, with the difference that the vertical range has been extended to `400` (I presume this is in milliseconds). They even show the exact intersection points and the corresponding offsets. Usually only a few input neurons will fire, in this case the ones with delay `> 0`. The no firing zone is usually `90%` of the maximum (in this case that would be `360`). Re Brian, you have to read the documentation to see how you should set up your networks.

Comment: Thanks cantordust for your great support.

Comment: Glad I could help!